# Filling up struct sockaddr_in from the ip header __be32 saddr and udp header __be16 source

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, endianness

I'm implementing a protocol in the **linux kernel** on top of UDP and want to send a reply from within the kernel when I receive a packet. For this, I want to run `ip4_datagram_connect` to get a route to the destination (which is the source address in the received packet) and then send a reply.

To call the `ip4_datagram_connect`, I need to fill in a sockaddr_in structure to pass as the address to the function. On comparing,

**struct sockaddr_in**

```
unsigned short   sin_port;           
struct in_addr   sin_addr;
```

**struct udphdr**

`__be16  source;`

and **struct iphdr**

`__be32  saddr;`

So my question is, do I need any helper function to copy the address and the port from the packet header into the sockaddr_in structure (like how we use htons etc. in socket programming)?

Answer (score 2):

The value in the raw IP and UDP header are already in network byte order. The `be` in e.g. `__be16` stands for "Big Endian", which is network byte order. The numbers in `__be16` and `__be32` is the number of bits.

The fields in the `sockadd_in` structures are also supposed to be in network byte order. The name `htons` stands for "Host To Network Short", i.e. it converts a `short` (which usually is 16 bits) from host byte order to network byte order.

So to answer your question: No, you do not need to do anything, plain assignment to `sin_port` and `sin_addr.s_addr` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and then report here :)